# netty http basic authentication

Tags: netty, basic-authentication

I used the example provided here
[Netty HTTP Authetication for Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609691/netty-http-authetication-for-client)
but still having 401 response

when I print the request header I  can see that all is good except one thing, the Authorization is:

```
Authorization: YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
```

When I do the same authentication with Chrome for instance, I have:

```
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
```

nothing special in netty doc about how to add Basic in the header

When I catch the failing message with a tool like [tcpmon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/) and resend the message by adding manually the Basic string, it works fine.

My question could be how to add Basic in the header submitted by netty ?

does someone faced this before ?

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did a hack in org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaders#addHeader method:

```
    void addHeader(final String name, final Object value) {
    validateHeaderName(name);
    String strVal = toString(value);
    HttpCodecUtil.validateHeaderValue(strVal);
    int h = hash(name);
    int i = index(h);

    if (Names.AUTHORIZATION.equals(name)) strVal = "Basic "+strVal;
    addHeader0(h, i, name, strVal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first header you are posted is not correct. It must look like the one of Chrome.

So in need you would just call HttpMessage.setHeader(...) and pass the values.

Comment: thnx but what args exactly to put in HttpMessage.setHeader(...) to have the Basic in your header ?

Comment: Also notice that in netty HttpCodecUtil validates you header name and spaces are not allowed so asof today I had to do a dirty hack on my side to make the Basic auth working fine.